# NHibernate -Temporarily turn off identity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql-server-ce, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I'm running an NHIbernate solution using SQL CE.
I am mapping one the fields in a table as below. 
However, in order to run some data imports I need to be able to temporarily turn off identity so I can import the data with its existing keys, then turn identity back on once the import has finished.

I've tried running a SQL query directly from the solution like this:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Article] ON");
```

but this seems to have no effect.

Is there any way to temporarily turn this on and off?

```
Property(x => x.ArticleId, m =>
{
    m.NotNullable(true);
    m.UniqueKey("UQ_Article_ArticleId");
    m.Column(cm => cm.SqlType("INT IDENTITY"));
    m.Generated(PropertyGeneration.Insert);
    m.Insert(true);
    m.Update(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something fairly simple in the end.

The sql line should have been this:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Article] ON").ExecuteUpdate();
```

and it needed to be inside a transaction. However, you can only do this on one table per transaction so didn't really help me that much.

Answer (score 0):

SQL should be a way to go, but I believe you have reversed the meaning of `IDENTITY_INSERT`.

To allow insert to identity column, you need to turn it to `ON`.

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Article] ON");
```

And after you have done your bulk inserted, turn it back to `OFF`.

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Article] OFF");
```

More details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but doesn't work. My example above was just showing how I'm executing the SQL. In practice I've been doing the way you mentioned. "On" first then "Off" afterwards.